# filter to a gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a gridview having column
names(batchname,firstname,schedule,startdate,enddate,labname)

I want to add a filter to a gridview. Can I add a filter bellow each column of the gridview header.Or Should i use it outside the gridview? Here I m using it outside the gridview.And fire a event of TextChanged.I have done following code but it doesnt work anymore.Please Suggest a solution.

I have to access data from three tables to show in gridview.The three
table formats are as below,

```
BatchMaster(batchmasterid,usermasterid,labmasterid,batchname,batchcode,batchdays,startdate,enddate)

UserMaster(usermasterid,title,firstname,middlename,lastname,phoneno);

LabMaster(labmasterid,labname);
```

I write a code on textbox change event whitch is taken outside the gridview.

```
protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data
Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMS;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");
           string query = "SELECT
batchmasterid,usermasterid,labmasterid,batchname,faculty,batchdays,startdate,enddate,LabMaster.labname
FROM BatchMaster,UserMaster Where batchname LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text
+ "%'";
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           da.Fill(ds);
           gvHeadload.DataSource = ds;
           gvHeadload.DataBind();

      }
```

also I have tried a Join Query. But it doesnt work anymore.
Pls suggest a solution as early as possible.
advanced thank u for ur suggation..

Comment: why can I smell a SQL injection waiting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should not create sql connection every time user types something. You should do it, for example after OnInitialize(). Second, you must open the connection: `con.Open()`, get data, store it in data set and close it `con.Close()`. Then you should filter the data set on text changed. There are also other ways of doing it, but I think this will be a good start.